# Which statistical test to analyse?

Tags: time-series, repeated-measures

I am trying to find out how inflammatory markers change in response to a mechanical device change. I have daily readings for the 5 days before the event and for the 5 days after the event. I am expecting a rise in inflammatory markers in the pre readings followed by a fall after the device change. I also need to find out how the change differs in two subgroups (sample sizes of the subgroups are n=21 and n=88). The aim is to find out if the change is significant, to consider these markers as predictors of the device failing and hence needing to be changed.

I would like to know what test would be appropriate to analyse this. I need to keep things simple as I and the people reading the results are non-statisticians.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Reeba. Do your pre and post readings form a time sequence with some substantial intervals between readings - i.e. they weren't all taken at around the same time? What are your sample sizes for the two subgroups?

Comment: HI.. Thank you. My pre values are daily reading for upto 5 days before event and similarly for post readings. My sample size of group 1 is 21 and group 2 is 88.

Comment: OK. No control group (in which the mechanical device was not changed)? I note that might not have been possible due to ethical considerations.

Comment: Yes. you are right there. It is not possible to have a control group here. This is what I am thinking. I met a statistician who suggested a GLM with emphasis on linear mixed model. But I dont understanding the terms on SPSS while trying to do it. I did some reading and thought of doing seperate one way repeated measures ANOVA on pre and post values. I am not sure if that is right though.

Comment: Adding to my previous statement. It could be possible to have a control group with patiets where in the device was never changes. However, this study does not include that. Hence, I am looking at pre and post values.

Comment: It is fairly straightforward to set up glm models in R (which I use with RStudio, both are freely downloadable). I expect it is also possible in SPSS but I'm not familiar with that software myself.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean when you say 'separate repeated-measures ANOVA'? (I suggest you edit this information into your question). Do you have some patients in which the device had failed and some in which it had not?

Comment: I am have downloaded the R-studie. do u mind talking me through how to the GLM. what I meant by seperate repeated measures is that since I have 5 repeated pre device change sample I do a repeated measures ANOVA to find significance and then do similarly for post values.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to give that amount of time today, but you can search for blogs online and answers on both stats.stackexchange and stackoverflow that will help take you through the steps for glm (and basic things like getting data into R).

Comment: I suspect that some sort of time-series analysis would be a more intelligent tool than a repeated measures ANOVA for this case. But I'm hoping that someone with more experience than me in dealing with time series data will be able to advise on that.

Comment: Are the readings pre- and post- totally random, or did you test the same pre-samples again after the device change? In order words if you had samples A, B, and C and tested them before the change, did you also then test A, B, and C, after or did you perhaps test new samples D, E, and F?

Comment: Hi...The pre and post test are in the same subjects

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate. I will try to give it go. Hopefully it will okai.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quick summary, and is in no way exhaustive: You can use the analyse/mixed model/linear tab for an LMER and the analyse/mixed model/generalized linear for a GLMM if you have binary/ordinal/etc. response variables. You then have to specify the subjects by dragging the appropriate variables into the subject box hierarchically. (E.g. people within classrooms within schools). In the fixed effects tab, you can specify your IVs by dragging them into the appropriate box. To add interactions, select all relevant variables and drag them together into the respective box (for a two-way interaction, select two variables and drag them into the "two-way" box.) You can add random effects the same way. If you only need a random intercept, tick "include intercept" in the random effects box, and set "subject combination" to whatever your subject variable is in the drop-down menu. To add random slopes, drag and drop your IVs the same way you did for random effects. In the "estimation" tab you can specify what pairwise contrasts you need in the case of categorial IVs, and what you want to save (z-scores, residuals, etc.). There are also some options related to different convergence criteria you can adjust if your model ends up not converging, but are better left alone at the outset. In addition, there are some additional settings you can use if your dataset is small, or if you need to use robust estimation, due to violations of model assumptions. Also, if you end up using the GLMM option, be sure to disable the "model viewer" in the edit/options menu, as it makes the GLMM output extremely cumbersome to navigate amd actually hides some important information.

Comment: The target will have to be whatever you are actually measuring, in this case, inflammatory markers. Time will need to be added as a fixed effect, but if it is theoretically sound to believe that time has a different effect for different subjects (for instance it has the opposite effect for some subjects) then you can also add time as a random slope in the random tab.